# For loop - missing last step if the output is NULL

Tags: r, for-loop

I have this example data

```
df<-data.frame(col=c(rep("YES",9),"NO"))
list<-list()
for(i in 1:10){
  if(df[i,1]=="YES"){
    list[[i]]<-"YES"
  }
  if(df[i,1]=="NO"){
    list[[i]]<-NULL
  }
}
```

Problem is that after this loop

```
length(list)=9
```

I find out that it is because of the NULL on the end. Any advices how to rewrite loop to show me the last output even if it is NULL?

Comment: Are you sure you want `NULL`, and not `NA`? Maybe, `ifelse(df$col=="YES","YES",NA)`

Comment: Yes, I am sure. I need NULL because of the character of the original data. I need the for loop to not miss the last step and shows the NULL ..

Comment: I fix it with using some "character" insted of NULL but I am still interest why it doesn't work

Comment: I can't imagine a scenario in which your list would be easier to work with than the equivalent logical vector `df[[i]] == "YES"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
df<-data.frame(mycol=c(rep("YES",9),"NO"))

mylist<-list()
for(i in 1:10){
  if(df[i,1]=="YES") mylist[i] <- "YES"
  if(df[i,1]=="NO") mylist[i] <- list(NULL)
}
```

Or you can use `ifelse`:

```
ifelse(df$mycol=="YES",list("YES"),ifelse(df$mycol=="NO",list(NULL),NA))
```

**There is a relevant post with a good explanation**: [Assigning NULL to a list element in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7944809/assigning-null-to-a-list-element-in-r)

Comment: Thank you, it is not that clear as I want it to be (mylist[[10]] is list in list) but I can handle it.