# try() and tryCatch() not working with R lists out of bounds

Tags: r

Basically i'm looping through items in a database which give me list objects from which i am trying to extract data. When i try to extract things from the list to a database, and When data is not available for a given object i will get the followign error:

```
>scd[a,paste0("b",".iss..",b)]= sc[["content"]][["abstracts-retrieval-response"]][["item"]][["bibrecord"]][["tail"]][["bibliography"]][["reference"]][[b]][["ref-info"]][["ref-volisspag"]][["voliss"]][["@issue"]]
Error in `*tmp*`[[jj]] : subscript out of bounds
```

when the error occurs it stops my loop. I simply want R to return NA when there is no infomation available, so how would i go about doign this. I've tried wrapping the above code around try({}) but it doesn't seem to fix the problem- I think this is because it only works for functions? is there an easy way to get it to work for the above?

I tried the following code:

```
scd[a,paste0("b",".vol..",b)]= as.numeric(tryCatch(sc[["content"]][["abstracts-retrieval-response"]][["item"]][["bibrecord"]][["tail"]][["bibliography"]][["reference"]][[b]][["ref-info"]][["ref-volisspag"]][["voliss"]][["@volume"]],error = function(e) NA))    
Error in `*tmp*`[[jj]] : subscript out of bounds
```

After the further investigation the issue arises because when there is no data available in the list it returns NULL rather than NA and then it cannot add this to the dataframe.

Comment: Show exactly what you did with `try`. `tryCatch` will work fine in this situation, but we can't tell what you did wrong unless you show us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tryCatch` will work for lists when the object doesn't actually exist:

```
test_list <- list(a = NULL, b = "some_value")
for(i in 1:3){
  obj <- tryCatch({
    x <- test_list[[i]]
    x <- ifelse(is.null(x), NA, x)
  }
  , error = function(e) NA)
  print(obj)
}
[1] NA
[1] "some_value"
[1] NA
```

Obviously, use with caution.

With your code:

```
scd[a,paste0("b",".iss..",b)] <- tryCatch({
  x <- sc[["content"]][["abstracts-retrieval-response"]][["item"]][["bibrecord"]][["tail"]][["bibliography"]][["reference"]][[b]][["ref-info"]][["ref-volisspag"]][["voliss"]][["@issue"]]
  x <- ifelse(is.null(x), NA, x)
}, error = function(e) NA)
```

Comment: I think the issue is that when there is no data it will return NULL rather than an error. For example this works (scd[a,paste0("b",".vol..",b)]= 3) but not (scd[a,paste0("b",".vol..",b)]= NULL), so maybe instead of using tryCatch i should use something to turn NULLs to NAs?

Comment: If that's your issue, just use `is.null` on an intermediate object assignment. Assigning `NULL` to a list element can do funny things: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7944809/assigning-null-to-a-list-element-in-r

Comment: @user3084100 please view my edits, hope this resolves your issues.