# Update a list/vector with nulls/nas inserted for missing

Tags: r

I have a list with known `expected` values.  Some of these values may be missing in the list I `have`.  How can I update the list to return `NULL` for the elements that are missing to give me what I `want`?

```
expected <- c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
have <- list(a=1, b=3, d=5)

want <- list(a=1, b=3, c=NULL, d=5)
```

I can do it like this but this seems a little hacky in that I have to rename the `NA`s.

```
x <- have[expected]
names(x) <- expected
x

## $a
## [1] 1
## 
## $b
## [1] 3
## 
## $c
## NULL
## 
## $d
## [1] 5
```

I want to keep the names for easy indexing later.

Comment: and for more background on [`NULL` and `NA`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7944809/assigning-null-to-a-list-element-in-r),

Comment: I can only think of more janky ways then you've posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option without creating an object is `setNames`

```
setNames(have[expected], expected)
#$a
#[1] 1

#$b
#[1] 3

#$c
#NULL

#$d
#[1] 5
```