# making the distinction between missing value types (non-response vs skip patterns)

Tags: r, dataframe

What would you recommend for making the distinction between missing value types for dataset users who might not read the codebook carefully?

In this toy example, `q2` is only asked to people who said "Yes" to `q1`. This means there is one missing value on `q2` that is missing because the person did not respond, and two missing values on `q2` that are missing because the question was not asked.

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble(q1 = c("Yes", "Yes", "No", "No"), 
             q2 = c("Yes", NA, NA, NA))

df

# A tibble: 4 x 2
  q1    q2   
  <chr> <chr>
1 Yes   Yes  
2 Yes   NA   
3 No    NA   
4 No    NA 

df %>% group_by(q1, q2) %>% count()

# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Groups:   q1, q2 [3]
  q1    q2        n
  <chr> <chr> <int>
1 No    NA        2
2 Yes   Yes       1
3 Yes   NA        1
```

When I summarize by `q2` there is no way in the dataset to make a distinction between missingness from non-response vs structural missingness.

```
df %>% group_by(q2) %>% count()

# A tibble: 2 x 2
# Groups:   q2 [2]
  q2        n
  <chr> <int>
1 Yes       1
2 NA        3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using NA, Inf, -Inf and NaN we can represent 4 categories of numeric missing values.  Below we show the use of NA with Inf and then NA with NaN.  In the third approach we discuss the use of naniar package.

**1)** Recode `q2` values of Yes, No, structural missing and missing to 1, 0, Inf and NA respectively.    Note that `is.na(x)` will only report TRUE for an actual NA, `is.infinite(x)` will only report TRUE for an Inf and  `!is.finite(x)` will report TRUE for NA or Inf in case you need to perform tests.  Optionally recode the output back.

```
df %>% 
  count(q2 = recode(q2, Yes = 1, No = 0, .missing = ifelse(q1 == "No", Inf, NA)))
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
# Groups:   q2 [3]
     q2     n
  <dbl> <int>
1     1     1
2   Inf     2
3    NA     1
```

**2)** A variation on this is to use NaN in place of Inf.  In that case tests can use `is.na(x)`, `is.nan(x)` and `!is.finite(x)`

```
df %>% 
  count(q2 = recode(q2, Yes = 1, No = 0, .missing = ifelse(q1 == "No", NaN, NA)))
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
     q2     n
  <dbl> <int>
1     1     1
2    NA     1
3   NaN     2
```

**3)**  The naniar package can create auxilliary columns that define the type of each NA using `bind_shadow`.  We can then recode the auxilliary columns using `recode_shadow` and then use those in our counting.

library(naniar)

```
library(naniar)
df %>%
  bind_shadow %>%
  recode_shadow(q2 = .where(is.na(q2) & q1 == "No" ~ "struct")) %>%
  count(q2, q2_NA)
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  q2    q2_NA         n
  <chr> <fct>     <int>
1 Yes   !NA           1
2 <NA>  NA            1
3 <NA>  NA_struct     2
```

Comment: Thanks, @GGrothendieck. Along the lines of {naniar} I found the {labelled} package that uses attributes.

Answer (score 2):

You could consider to code your variables numerically, which also reduces the file size.

To quickly convert what you already have, do:

```
df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) ifelse(x == "Yes", 1, 2))
#   q1 q2
# 1  1  1
# 2  1 NA
# 3  2 NA
# 4  2 NA
```

Different kinds of NA's are usually encoded with unmistakable<sup>*</sup> values such as `-77` `-99`.

<sup>*However, try to replicate some highly cited papers!</sup>

```
nas <- is.na(df$q2)
df[nas, 'q2'] <- with(df[nas, ], ifelse(q1 == 2, -77, -99))
df
#   q1  q2
# 1  1   1
# 2  1 -99
# 3  2 -77
# 4  2 -77
```

In your "physical" code book then write:

```
#   1: "Yes"
#   2: "No"
# -77: "inapplicable"
# -99: "missing"
```

With this information your data can easily be decoded using `factor`s:

```
df1 <- df
df1[] <- lapply(df1, function(x) 
  factor(x, levels=c(1, 2, -77, -99), 
         labels=c("Yes", "No", "inapplicable", "missing")))
df1
#    q1           q2
# 1 Yes          Yes
# 2 Yes      missing
# 3  No inapplicable
# 4  No inapplicable
```

It is obvious that this approach can also be extended to any number of types of missings, e.g.

```
# -66: not valid
# -88: not asked
# -55: not reached
# ...
```

##### Add code book in attributes

It's also possible to add the code book in the attributes. Store information for each variable in a list and `Map` them on your data frame using `` `attr<-` ``.

```
a <-
  list(q1=c(`1`='Yes', `2`='No', `-77`='inapliccable', `-88`='invalid', `-99`='missing'),
       q1=c(`1`='Yes', `2`='No', `-77`='inapliccable', `-88`='invalid', `-99`='missing'))

df[] <- Map(`attr<-`, df, 'foo', a)
```

This avoids mistakes when typing in the codebook.

```
df2 <- df

df2[] <- lapply(df2, function(x) 
  factor(x, levels=names(attr(x, 'foo')), labels=attr(x, 'foo')))
df2
#    q1           q2
# 1 Yes          Yes
# 2 Yes      missing
# 3  No inapliccable
# 4  No inapliccable
```

Answer (score 1):

R has several special values that behave something like `NA`:  `Inf`, `NaN`, etc.  But none of them behave exactly like `NA`, so they are all compromises.
A solution that works better (and is much more flexible) was posted here:  https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2021-May/080776.html .

The idea is to create a new "class" called `"MultiMissing"` that adds an attribute to distinguish between different kinds of missingness.  Here's some code to do it:

```r
asMultiMissing <- function(x) {
  if (isMultiMissing(x))
    return(x)
  missingKind <- ifelse(is.na(x), 1, NA)
  structure(x, 
            missingKind = missingKind, 
            class = c("MultiMissing", class(x)))
}

isMultiMissing <- function(x)
  inherits(x, "MultiMissing")

missingKind <- function(x) {
  if (isMultiMissing(x))
    attr(x, "missingKind")
  else
    ifelse(is.na(x), 1, NA)
}

`missingKind<-` <- function(x, value) {
  class(x) <- setdiff(class(x), "MultiMissing")
  x[!is.na(value)] <- NA
  x <- asMultiMissing(x)
  attr(x, "missingKind") <- value
  x
}

`[.MultiMissing` <- function(x, i, ...) {
  missings <- missingKind(x)
  x <- NextMethod()
  missings <- missings[i]
  missingKind(x) <- missings
  x
}

print.MultiMissing <- function(x, ...) {
  vals <- format(x, ...)
  if (is.character(x) && !inherits(x, "noquote"))
    vals <- ifelse(is.na(x), vals, paste0('"', vals, '"'))
  print(noquote(vals))
  invisible(x)
}

`[<-.MultiMissing` <- function(x, i, value, ...) {
  missings <- missingKind(x)
  class(x) <- setdiff(class(x), "MultiMissing")
  x[i] <- value
  missings[i] <- missingKind(value)
  missingKind(x) <- missings
  x
}

format.MultiMissing <- function(x, ...) {
  missings <- missingKind(x)
  result <- NextMethod()
  ifelse(!is.na(missings),
         paste0("NA.", missings), result)
  
}

pillar_shaft.MultiMissing <- function(x, ...) {
  pillar::pillar_shaft(format(x))
}

q2 <- c("Yes", NA, NA, NA)
missingKind(q2) <- c(NA, "missing", "inapplicable", "inapplicable")
q2
#> [1] "Yes"           NA.missing      NA.inapplicable NA.inapplicable
df <- data.frame(q2 = q2)
df
#>                q2
#> 1             Yes
#> 2      NA.missing
#> 3 NA.inapplicable
#> 4 NA.inapplicable
tib <- tibble::tibble(q2 = q2)
tib
#> # A tibble: 4 × 1
#>   q2             
#>   <MltMssng>     
#> 1 Yes            
#> 2 NA.missing     
#> 3 NA.inapplicable
#> 4 NA.inapplicable

library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
df %>% group_by(format(q2)) %>% count()
#> # A tibble: 3 × 2
#> # Groups:   format(q2) [3]
#>   `format(q2)`        n
#>   <chr>           <int>
#> 1 NA.inapplicable     2
#> 2 NA.missing          1
#> 3 Yes                 1
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You can give a `NULL` to those where it is not possible to give an answer.

```
df <- data.frame(q1 = c("Yes", "Yes", "No", "No")
               , q2 = c("Yes", NA, NA, NA))
df$q2[df$q1 != "Yes"] <- list(NULL)

library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(q2) %>% count() %>% as.data.frame()
#    q2 n
#1  Yes 1
#2   NA 1
#3 NULL 2
```

Or you give an `attr`.

```
df <- data.frame(q1 = c("Yes", "Yes", "No", "No")
               , q2 = c("Yes", NA, NA, NA))
attr(df$q2, "skip") <- ifelse(df$q1 != "Yes", " Skip", "")

df %>% group_by(q2=paste0(q2, attr(q2, "skip"))) %>% count()
#  q2          n
#  <chr>   <int>
#1 NA          1
#2 NA Skip     2
#3 Yes         1
```

Comment: R is inconsistent when using NULL in a list. Constructing it as you did works, but assigning NULL to an entry removes that entry. So I'd recommend avoiding it completely as a data value.

Comment: @user2554330 I think R is *NOT* inconsistent! Please see update or e.g. [Assigning NULL to a list element in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7944809/10488504)

Comment: This isn't a place for a discussion, but by "inconsistent", I mean `NULL` is handled differently than other objects.

Comment: @user2554330 Maybe that's because `NULL` is not a value. Yes I agree that some might use `df$q2[df$q1 != "Yes"] <- NULL` and are removing the values. But I think it could be used to distinguish between Missing Values (`NA`) and undefined values (`NULL`). The advantage might be, that it will work for *all* kind of types and will *not disable* any potentially possible value.