# Replace the values in a named numeric by its attribute value.label

Tags: r

I have a sample df that looks like:

```
sample <- structure(list(
  var = structure(c(1, 2, 2, 3, 2), 
                  value.labels = c(
                    no = 3, `yes, opinion` = 2, `yes, decision` = 1))), 
  row.names = c(NA, -5L), 
  class = "data.frame")
```

Obviously `sample$var` is a categorical variable and the *levels* are stored in the attributes of the vector `var`:

```
attributes(sample$var)
# $value.labels
#       no  yes, opinion yes, decision 
#        3             2             1
```

..but I can't make sense of those attributes..

For example `table(sample$var)` doesn't show them:

```
table(sample$var)

# 1 2 3 
# 1 3 1
```

And also any attempts to bring them to 'life' by `as.factor` (and - desperately searching - `as.character`) didn't work out.

---

*How can I replace those values with their corresponding labels?*
*Expected output can be a vector of class factor or string..*

---

*And a bit 'around' the question: What exactly is the idea behind that kind of named vectors (in addition to the factor class..)?*

Comment: In addition to *@GKi's* excellent [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69190887/6574038), the benefits might be 1. avoiding errors while typing in from code books, and 2. decode information on missing value types. You may want to see my answer there: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69178894/6574038

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try *to bring them to life*:

```
. <- attr(sample$var, "value.labels")
table(factor(sample$var, ., names(.)))
#           no  yes, opinion yes, decision 
#            1             3             1
```

or overwrite:

```
. <- attr(sample$var, "value.labels")
sample$var <- factor(sample$var, ., names(.))
```

Answer (score 2):

You may add a new column with labels. Then you can use `table` or other functions on them as usual.

```
tmp <- attributes(sample$var)$value.labels
sample$label <- names(tmp)[match(sample$var, tmp)]
sample

#  var         label
#1   1 yes, decision
#2   2  yes, opinion
#3   2  yes, opinion
#4   3            no
#5   2  yes, opinion

table(sample$label)

#           no yes, decision  yes, opinion 
#            1             1             3
```